# WordPress: Push.js implementation of the ServiceWorker causes problems

Tags: javascript, php, android, node.js, wordpress

Where should I begin? So first of all let me explain my idea:

To make the visit of my site / blog (made with WordPress) more interactively I've had the very great idea to implement push notifications for my users to notify them about important news. So I've searched some time and found this framework:

https://github.com/Nickersoft/push.js

This was originally made for NodeJS (install via npm and all the stuff) but I thought it should work with WordPress too and started with the implementation.

---

First I've downloaded the whole `.zip` from GitHub and extracted the `push.min.js` uploaded it to my server and included it via my `functions.php` file in my child theme:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'service-worker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/serviceWorker.js' );
```

After that I've tried to create a new Push like in the example in my themes `main.js` file:

```
Push.create("Slap me!", {
    body: "I'm a bad girl.",
    link: 'google.de',
    icon: ''
});
```

After saving it and reloading the page the notification get's send / shown successfully. So I've tried it on my smartphone and on 2 other phones but there is no notification shown (just the notice to accept notifications from my page).

Because of this I've started a big research and found some "bugs" for this topic. But they are not helpful because I'm using WordPress and not a WebApp. To bring it to the point: I need a `serviceWorker` for mobile support!

---

So I've uploaded the `serviceWorker.js` from the downloaded `.zip` to my server and included it too:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'service-worker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/serviceWorker.js' );
```

But it's still not working on mobile phones!!! The files are visible under sources but it's simply not working.

Also this don't made it:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://localhost/wp-content/themes/custom/js/serviceWorker.js', {scope: '/'});
```

So I really don't know how to get this running. Can you please help me? There is absolutely no documentation to use it with WordPress.

Comment: Let me paraphrase this to see if understand it correctly. _I found a javascript library to do desktop notifications and I tried jamming it into my Wordpress site. Now I want to know why it doesn't work on a mobile device._ Is that about right?

Comment: @gforce301 My company would love you: My requirements in one sentence. You are absolutely right! But the goal was to display the whole process and what I've did to make it all clear.